# Curl fails with SSL errors 56 and 35 when talking to a HTTPS Python web server

Tags: python, ssl, curl

I have setup my own HTTPS server using Python:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello, secure world!\n')

httpd = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 4443), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain(
        certfile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/.../fullchain.pem",
        keyfile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/.../privkey.pem")
httpd.socket = context.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

For security purposes, my server runs in a VirtualBox VM with port forwarding from 443 to 4443. When I query the HTTPS server via curl locally on the VM, I get a response, but there is also an error:

```
$ curl -k 'https://locahost:4443'
Hello, secure world!
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading, errno 0
```

However, when I try to query it from the host, I only get an error:

```
$ curl -k 'https://127.0.0.1'
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 127.0.0.1:443
```

As you can see, in both calls I disable cert verification because I query my server by IP address and not the actual domain. The certs are for my personal domain and are signed by letsencrypt.com. When I tried using an actual domain on the host, I get the same error (34).

Why do I get errors in the curl call in the guest VM and why is it different when calling from the host?

Comment: The first error probably means you are not sending a properly formatted HTTP response. My guess is that the trailing new line might be a problem, but I'm not sure. Try removing the `\n` and see if it works. If it still doesn't solve the error, then you will need to print the raw response and see what's wrong.

Comment: For the second error, I don't think HTTPS is allowed for 127.0.0.1, but then I was surprised it works for `localhost` in the first example. Beyond that, double check that you have correctly configured port 443 on the host to forward to port 4443 on the VM.

Comment: Removed newline from code and with 127.0.0.1 in the Guest VM: `curl -k 'https://127.0.0.1:4443'`. Got the same result: `Hello, secure world!curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading, errno 0`.

Comment: Port forwarding seems to work: I have tested with plain HTTP server running on port 4443: `python -m http.server 4443`. Curl worked both in guest VM: `curl 'http://127.0.0.1:4443'` and on the host `curl 'http://127.0.0.1:443'`. In both cases I got the content of the dir in which server runs and no errors.

Comment: Found bug in my code. `HTTPServer` needs to be constructed with `('0.0.0.0', 4443)` to allow connections from other hosts. This fixes the issue with `curl` from the host, but the curl error from inside guest is still present

Comment: That's such a strange coincidence. I encountered a similar problem with IP addresses in one of my own projects recently. As for the "unexpected eof" error, I recommend finding a way that you can inspect the raw HTTP response. It's been a long time since I worked at this low level, so I don't have any specifics to suggest for debugging. Is there a reason you are mucking around with HTTP directly rather than using a framework like Flask or Django?

Comment: It's a pet project for fun. I thought setting up a server using frameworks will take more time than simple script like this. I'll play around some more with raw responses and read some specs to understand the error.

Comment: If you are doing this to learn HTTP at a very low level, then this is a fine way to go. If your goal, on the other hand, is to create a functioning web service, even as a pet project, then I recommend using a framework such as FastAPI, Flask, or Django. They are very quick to get started with and even quicker to make progress with over doing raw HTTP responses yourself, especially when you have any amount of complexity in your API logic.

Comment: Yes, I want to go low level, although I am more interested in DNS than HTTP. Just wanted to make sure I use HTTPS. It's kinda anticlimactic to still use HTTP these days...

Answer (score 1):

Found bug in my code. `HTTPServer` needs to be constructed with `('0.0.0.0', 4443)` to allow connections from other hosts.